# How to call a Selenium command (ie. echo) within user extension?

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

When working on Selenium user-extension, how can you call a Selenium Command?
When debugging Selenium User Extension, how can you echo/console.log ?

Could find the answer on the internet so I'm posting my own answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a Selenium Command in user-extension.js, you need to use this syntax

```
this.doCommandName(param)
```

ie, to call echo

```
Selenium.prototype.doMyFunction = function(){
     this.doEcho("This info will show on logs");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works even better. As now the debug messages of your user extension are similar as the debug and info messages of 'build-in' commands.

```
Selenium.prototype.doYourCommand = function(strTarget, strValue) {
    LOG.debug("begin: doBaseURL | " + strTarget + " | " + strValue + " |");
    LOG.info(strValue);
    LOG.debug("end: doBaseURL | " + strTarget + " | " + strValue + " |");
}
```